# transfer data in symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I have created two functions in controller of Symfony as follow:

first is `newAction`

```
public function newAction()
{
    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
}
```

then `subAction`

```
public function subAction()
{
    echo "hello";
}
```

I want to use some data from `index.html.twig` into `subAction` function.

How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to use

```
$content = $this->renderView('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:index.html.twig')
```

This will render contents of template in variable

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#rendering-templates

**EDIT** according to comment

If you need to render only part of template - then you should refactor your templates.

Exclude that part of code from your **index.html.twig** into separate template file and include it in **index.html.twig**:

```
...
{% include 'AcmeTaskBundle:Default:subpage.html.twig' %}
...
```

And then in your **subAction()** call:

```
    $content = $this->renderView('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:subpage.html.twig')
```

Comment: it the part in index.html stores the values dynamically then how it will store in subpage.html.twig

Comment: Sorry, did not get the question. Could you explain in details with better example?

Comment: i am designing a dynamic form builder. what i am doing is i have created button like text box, text area etc. as i click the button then the generated code is stored in a text area. now i want to show the value of that textarea(i.e. the generated code) in the SubAction,

Comment: Why don't you POST this text to an action using AJAX then? :)

Comment: can you give me some reference that how i can make an ajax request

Comment: Sorry, but there is no such easy reference... You should read documentation about jQuery, http specification and so on...
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/